# Dependency injection fails when using an inherited class from IdentityUser targeting net6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

In Program.cs `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>` works but `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>` produces in the following error after `return View();` is called: `InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.`

ApplicationDbContext:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace AuthSample.Data;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

WebAppUser:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace AuthSample.Data;

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

I am using dotnet --version 6.0.100 targeting net6.0 on Fedora 34.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build an ApplicationUser model in /Models/Identity/ with code something like this?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

And then map to ApplicationUser is Programs and add the required references.

Comment: Yes, but in Program.cs `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();` works and `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();` fails.

Comment: Likely you are missing a reference then. using Namespace.Models